# Do not show the missing (detatime) data in the Highchart Area Charts

Tags: highcharts

Although there is a 9 hour data interruption on 3 February, data seems to have arrived.

```
data: [
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,0),308.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,1),273],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,2),271],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,3),304],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,4),302],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,5),301],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,6),311.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,7),329.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,8),370.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,9),533.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,10),728],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,11),739],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,12),744],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,13),740],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,14),748.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,15),751],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,16),765],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,17),730],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,18),789.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,19),778.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,20),762],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,21),743.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,22),356.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,2,23),250],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,0),185.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,1),111],

  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,10),117.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,11),750],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,12),673.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,13),730.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,14),756.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,15),733],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,16),759.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,17),763.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,18),776],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,19),775],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,20),765.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,21),748],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,22),356.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,3,23),259],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,0),260],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,1),239],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,2),234],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,3),244],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,4),246],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,5),247],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,6),250.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,7),275],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,8),340],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,9),485],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,10),711.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,11),714.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,12),731],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,13),743],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,14),756.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,15),761.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,16),752],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,17),808],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,18),736.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,19),772],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,20),760.5],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,21),741],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,22),390],
  [Date.UTC(2018,1,4,23),219.5]]
  }],
```

[I do not want this to happen.](https://resmim.net/f/qDl3s6.png)

I do not want to see anything in this area. I can not remove this area. Can you look at the codes and tell me how to remove this area?

http://jsfiddle.net/f9emysax/

Comment: You can add `plotOptions:{ connectNulls: false},` before `series`  and insert a datapoint with value `null` in the 9-hour gap if possible. http://jsfiddle.net/f9emysax/6/

Comment: If you change to highstock the gap will be removed (because [`ordinal: true`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal) is set by default). Example; http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/f9emysax/8/